# Button Action in JavaFX executes in a wrong sequence

Tags: java, button, controller, javafx, initialization

**Update 1**: Here is a more interesting thing. When i delete the last line { mainapp.showReportingScreen() ;}  now program first execute the findAplliedJars method then show processing screen.

---

I'm working in JavaFX and struggling with actions of a button. What I want is, when that button is clicked:

1. do something;
2. show another screen;
3. do another thing;
4. show another screen;

But, my program skips the 2. point.

Here is my code:

```
public class SomeController implements Initializable {
    .
    .
    .
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
           .
           .
           .
    someButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {             

            Report.setUserName(userNameField.getText());
            Report.setPassword(passwordField.getText());
            Report.setSmAdress(smAdressField.getText());
            mainApp.showProcessingScreen();
            Report.findAppliedJars();
            mainApp.showReportingScreen();

        }
    });        
}   
    . 
    .
    .
}
```

So, without showing **processingScreen**, my program executes **findAppliedJars()** and then shows **reportingScreen**.

What may be the problem? Thanks.

---

**Update 2**: Here is my showProcessingScreen() method:

```
public void showProcessingScreen() {
        try {
            // Load Report Screen
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();               
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("ProcessingScreen.fxml"));         
            AnchorPane processingScreen = (AnchorPane) loader.load();           
            // Set report screen into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(processingScreen);
            ProcessingScreenController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `processingScreen` ?

Comment: Probably execution is not stoped on showing of your processing screen

Comment: I will post the code in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you somehow pause the execution, the program will continue to execute, and essentially skip over the showing of your processing screen. To show your processing screen for a certain amount of time you need to use an [animation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html) and show your reporting screen once the animation has finished. Note the code below is only an outline of what your end result may look like and does not compile.

```
Transition transition;
// Set up your transition or animation
transition = buildTransition();
// Show your processing screen within the transition
showProcessingScreen();
transition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Report.findAppliedJars();
        mainApp.showReportingScreen();
    }       
});
```

If you are trying to load something in the background while the processing screen is showing then you will have to use [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm). If you go this route, the code should look similar to the above, except you would be using the [Task class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and the [setOnSucceeded method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29). There are other ways to perform this operation, but I believe this is the simplest way.

Comment: Actually the findAplliedJars method takes some time. So I thought while that method was running, the processingscreen should be seen. Now I wait for findAplliedJars method to finish, then comes reportingscreen.

Comment: Yeah in that case you need to use the Task class.